# SKLIghtNode with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have a player in the center of the screen, which I'd like to be the "source" of the light, so every other sprite, such as flying enemies, are casting a shadow.

I have this code:

```
 light.categoryBitMask = 1
    light.falloff = 1
    light.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    light.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(light)
```

I'm totally new to Swift, never had any experience with SpriteKit, so I figured out that I should add this to every Sprite:

```
    enemyOne.shadowCastBitMask = 1
```

What I get is quite interesting. The screen flickers everytime an enemy sprite is being spawned. But other than that, and a really small light in the center of the screen, where my player is, I'm not getting any shadows.

To make my plan more clear, I'd like to make it look like this:

[image]

This is what it looks like, as requested:

[image]

Comment: could you show us what you ARE getting and not what you expect? It would help, thanks

Comment: here's the picture ^. As you can see, the "enemies", as in, flying shapes are not really affected, and you can't really see anything, even thought the bit map is set.

Comment: could you try setting the ambient and light color of the light node? Other than that, the only problem I could see is you having an error somewhere. Can you post more code? One more possibility, I don't have much experience with adding the enemies after the SKLightNode is initialized. Could that be a problem?